# Literature that connects analysis 1&2 with linear algebra 1&2? How they meet?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Does anyone know a good book (or another info source) that describes in detail how fundamental concepts of analysis 1 & 2 connect to fundamental concepts of linear algebra 1 & 2?

Context of these courses:

**Lin. Algebra** started with the concept of Groups(algebraic structures) and ended with Quadric.

**Analysis** started with the concepts of sequences/series and ended with ordinary differential equations (2nd order).

Comment: The connection is that when you go to analysis in several variables the computations are done with vectors and matrices. These computations are not necessarily linear, *but* the concept of derivative is extended by approximating functions with linear maps.

Comment: Does your linear algebra include vector spaces and matrices?  Does your analysis include multivariate calculus?

Comment: Yes @Henry they do.